# Removing Nepomuk and Akonadi

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 14.04, akonadi, nepomuk

Now that we have Baloo in KDE I guess is safe to remove the Akonadi and Nepomuk, right?

I have upgraded my Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 without any problem. In the upgrade process, the system removed some packages but not the packages related with akonadi and nepomuk:

```
libnepomuk4                                     install
libnepomukcleaner4                              install
libnepomukcore4abi1                             install
libnepomukquery4a                               install
libnepomukutils4                                install
libnepomukwidgets4                              install
nepomuk-core-data                               install
nepomuk-core-runtime                            install
akonadi-backend-mysql                           install
akonadi-server                                  install
libakonadi-calendar4                            install
libakonadi-contact4                             install
libakonadi-kabc4                                install
libakonadi-kcal4                                install
libakonadi-kde4                                 install
libakonadi-kmime4                               install
libakonadi-notes4                               install
libakonadi-socialutils4                         install
libakonadiprotocolinternals1                    install
```

Is it safe to remove this packages?, do I need to do something more? My intention is to remove completely Akonadi and Nepomuk as they are no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simulation**

At here, new 14.04 installation with the KDE desktop.

Running a simulation - what will happen if I remove the 'libnepomuk4':

```
apt-get purge -s libnepomuk4
```

The result:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>
> adobe-flash-properties-kde*
>   apport-kde* apturl-kde* ark* audiocd-kio* baloo*   bluedevil* dolphin*
>   dolphin+* ffmpegthumbs* filelight* freespacenotifier*
>
> ...
>
> sweeper* systemsettings* usb-creator-kde* user-manager*
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>
> at-spi2-core
>   libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
>   libgtk-3-common libwayland-cursor0 policykit-1-gnome xterm
>
> 0 upgraded,
>   9 newly installed, 211 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Full output: http://pastebin.com/wHF82M9P

Well - Maybe not...

**Akonadi**

Akonadi: http://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi

> The Akonadi framework is responsible for providing applications with a
>   centralized database to store, index and retrieve the user's personal
>   information. This includes the user's emails, contacts, calendars,
>   events, journals, alarms, notes, etc...

**Nepomuk & Baloo**

The Nepomuk was replaced with the Baloo - http://community.kde.org/Baloo

Answer (score 1):

I had working nepomuk in Kubuntu for a long time.  I've upgraded Kubuntu to 14.04 and then 14.10, and FWIW I no longer have any nepomuk packages installed, only baloo. So one of those upgrades removed nepomuk for me.  I didn't try to remove akonadi packages; Akonadi isn't causing any problems beyond the AkonadiTray widget that never does anything.

The Kubuntu upgrade did not delete the obsolete index files in `~/.kde/share/apps/nepomuk` which will recover 100 MBs of space, maybe it should (I filed [launchpad bug 1402463].  I updated https://userbase.kde.org/Nepomuk to mention it's safe to remove these old files, I'm not sure where else to say it.