# Removing Nepomuk in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nepomuk

How can I completely remove Nepomuk and all it's components in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: In general the method to remove it is to reverse the installation process. So how did you install it?

Comment: I didn't install it... it was included by default

Comment: No it was not. It is part of KDE and will never get install on Ubuntu unless you tell it to (by installing KDE software). And have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453422/removing-nepomuk-and-akonay that probably shows all you need(?)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at giving it a try, but you will most likely run into problems.

```
apt-get purge -s libnepomuk4
```